# Inheritance versus referencing other class inside my asp.net mvc & Entity framework application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, object-oriented-analysis

i am working on an asp.net mvc web application. and i have defined many view model classes, which reference  separate model classes from different sources as follow (where i postfix these classes with the word "Join") since they join separate model classes that are defined inside different DB table:-

```
public class ServerJoin : IValidatableObject
{
    public Server Server { get; set; }
    public Resource Resource { get; set; }
    public Technology Technology { get; set; }
    public SDOrganization Site { get; set; }
    public SDOrganization Customer { get; set; }
    public NetworkInfo NetworkInfo { get; set; }
    public ICollection<NetworkInfo> NetworkInfo2 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Unique")]
    public bool IsMACUnique { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Unique")]
    public bool IsIPUnique { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> SPEED { get; set; }
    public Nullable<Int64> PROCESSORCOUNT { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "IP Unique")]
    public bool IsTIPUnique { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "MAC Unique")]
    public bool IsTMACUnique { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (Server != null)
        {


            if (Server.RackUnitID != null && Server.RackID == null)
            {
                yield return new ValidationResult("Please select a Rack, or remove the current Rack Unit", new[] { "Server.RackUnitID" });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

& another view model class:-

```
public class VMJoin
{
     public VirtualMachine VirtualMachine { get; set; }
     public Resource Resource { get; set; }
     public Technology Technology { get; set; }
     public SDOrganization Site { get; set; }
     public SDOrganization Customer { get; set; }
     public NetworkInfo NetworkInfo { get; set; }
     public ICollection<NetworkInfo> NetworkInfo2 { get; set; }
     public ICollection<TechnologyIP> TechnologyIP { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Unique")]
     public bool IsMACUnique { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "Unique")]
     public bool IsIPUnique { get; set; }
     public Nullable<double> SPEED { get; set; }
     public TechnologyIP TechnologyIP2 { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "IP Unique")]
     public bool IsTIPUnique  { get; set; }
     [Display(Name = "MAC Unique")]
     public bool IsTMACUnique { get; set; }

}
```

now i want to define a shared class properties for all the view models, this general class , is used to call external API , the class looks as follow:-

```
public class GeneralClass
{
     public string ResourceName { get; set; }
     public string ResourceDesc { get; set; }
     public string ResourceType { get; set; }
}
```

now i am not sure how i can reference this class inside the view models. i am searching for a way to define this class as a parent class and force the other classes (serverjoin & vmjoin) to extend this GeneralClass?. the other option (which mimic how Entity framework manage classes) is just to add a reference of the GeneralClass inside the Serverjoin & VMjoin ?? so can anyone adivce on this please ?

Thanks

Comment: EF will handle inheritance or composition. You need to decide if ServerJoin "is a" GeneralClass (inheritance) or ServerJoin "has a" GeneralClass (composition). http://www.w3resource.com/java-tutorial/inheritance-composition-relationship.php

Comment: @SteveGreene i need it to be "is a" but not sure how i will extend my serverjoin in this case as it already extend IValidatableObject?

Answer (score 0):

IValidatableObject is an interface so you can use:

```
public class ServerJoin : GeneralClass, IValidatableObject
{
   ...
}
```

I'm not sure that makes sense from a ViewModel perspective. I usually do the inheritance in my entity models and then flatten things out in my ViewModels.

Comment: but how do you do the inheritance inside you entity models ? now i am following the DB first approach, where i use EF to map my Db tables,, and i never get any type of inheritance inside my auto generated model classes .. i mean EF seems to always follow composition over inheritance , when following DB first approach ...not sure how things work when following code first approach ..

Comment: You need to delete the relationships and add inheritance. See here: https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/entity-framework-db-first-%25E2%2580%2593-inheritance-relationships-between-entities

Comment: ok thanks for your link,, so my question is will i get any advantages if i modify how EF mapped my tables  to have an inheritance-like model classes? or it is fine to work in the way EF map the model classes by using compositions ?

Comment: You'll get mixed opinions, but I've always stuck with composition. Inheritance adds complexity and composition seems like a better abstraction for relational data.

Comment: so it is fine to keep things as is with composition? what do you think ?

Comment: I think yes unless there are numerous child classes that derive.